# Не отображается нужный цвет фрагмента строки при выводе ANSI кодов в QTextEdit

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, color

Пытаюсь отобразить фрагмент строки в нужном цвете. Задаю цвет в методе format.  Он отображается только в функции print(). Почему не отображается в строках виджетов PyQt5?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QTextEdit, QLabel
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.resize(300, 100)

word = "{blue}{0}{endcolor} {1}"\
    .format("-ABC def-", "1111", blue='\033[96m', endcolor='\033[0m')

print(word)
txt = QTextEdit(word)
lbl = QLabel(word)

vbox = QVBoxLayout()
vbox.addWidget(txt)
vbox.addWidget(lbl)
window.setLayout(vbox)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: связанный пример: [как qtconsole реализует ANSI кода](https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole/blob/9fa2d40e6be2eed5aa0ae9b429cde7681ec89254/qtconsole/ansi_code_processor.py)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что, в `QLabel` и `QTextEdit` для цветного текста нужно писать `HTML`, а в консоли цвет выделялся как раз потому что это консоль.

Сделайте так:

```
word = '<font color="blue">{0}</font> {1}'.format("-ABC def-", "1111")
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Если я указываю  ширину и цвет в методе format почему  ширина не работает?           `word = '<font color="red">{0:15}</font> {1:15}'.format("-ABC def-", "1111")`

Comment: потому что, это HTML, а там лишние пробелы игнорируются, поэтому каждый пробел нужно заменять на `&nbsp;`, либо в специальном теге отображать ваш текст: http://htmlbook.ru/html/pre

Comment: Спасибо! Не додумался бы что дело в html, уверен был что особенность PyQt.

Comment: Отметьте тогда ответ как правильный

Comment: "потому что это консоль", *которая поддерживает VT100 терминальные последовательности* (что на Windows специально надо включать или что-то вроде colorama модуля использовать). Можно аналог colorama для QTextEdit реализовать. [QTextEdit and colored bash-like output emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26500429/4279)

Comment: @gil9red для отображения жирного шрифта в `QTextEdit` используется html или есть другой способ?

Comment: Либо сразу через html (`<b>Жирный</b> текст`), либо через внутренние структуры. [Делал простенький редактор](https://github.com/gil9red/NotesManager) и там такую возможность делал: https://github.com/gil9red/NotesManager/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=user%3Agil9red+on_bold_clicked&type= и само выделение в жирный: https://github.com/gil9red/NotesManager/blob/90864c80674bdd88540eed9147b9c58d34fc355b/FormattingToolbar/FormattingToolbar.cpp#L453